# Google chrome Inspect element not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, debugging, javascript-debugger, inspect-element

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tBwx.png)

I want to reach a break point in 'Sources' tab of inspect element.But when i open the 'sources' tab it will become blank. 
Can't debug.
but some times it is coming.help me to find a solution.

Comment: click on element tab

Comment: @kushalkant i want to open 'Sources' tab.But its not working.Its become blank.

Comment: Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Can you please provide more information like, what kind of project you are running? are you enabled Optimizations in configuration file in case it's .net web application with Bundling?

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall and reinstall chrome. If you use a 64bit operating system, you can set up 64 bit chrome.